# How to detach mock function from the react component's prototype so that will not affect other test?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have two tests in first test i have mocked handleTextChange method to know that it has been called with text change.

In second test i don't want to mock it any more rather i want its real implementation to be called.

TodoForm.jsx file

```
export class TodoForm extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            txtValue: ""
        }

        this.handleTxtChange = this.handleTxtChange.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick = () => {
        console.log("handle click is called");
    }


    handleTxtChange(e) {
        console.log("i am called", e.target.value);
        this.setState({ txtValue: e.target.value });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="enter task name" value={this.state.txtValue} onChange={this.handleTxtChange} />
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Clik</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

in my test file

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import { TodoForm } from "../todoform";


it("must call the handeTxtchange with change text of textbox", () => {

    //in this test i want to mock handleTxtChange to 
    //know that is has been called with text cahnge


    const mocked = jest.fn((e) => console.log("mock get called", e.target.value));

    TodoForm.prototype.handleTxtChange = mocked;

    const wrapper = shallow(<TodoForm />);

    wrapper.find("input[type='text']").simulate("change", { target: { value: "hello" } });

    expect(mocked).toHaveBeenCalled();


});


it("user must be able to type in inputbox", () => {

    //in this test i don't want to mock the handleTxt change anymore 
    //(but it calls the mock function of previous test)


    const wrapper = shallow(<TodoForm />);

    wrapper.find("input[type='text']").simulate("change", { target: { value: "hello" } });
    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.find("input[type='text']").prop("value")).toEqual("hello");
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first `it` block, you can use a jest `spy` instead of assigning the mocked function as the new value of `handleTxtChange`.

```js
it("must call the handeTxtchange with change text of textbox", () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(TodoForm.prototype, 'handleTxtChange');

    const wrapper = shallow(<TodoForm />);

    wrapper.find("input[type='text']").simulate("change", { target: { value: "hello" } });

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
   
    // don't forget to clear the spy
    spy.mockClear();
});
```

If you really want to mock the function, then restore the original implementation afterwards then you can do this.

```js
it("must call the handeTxtchange with change text of textbox", () => {
    const mocked = jest.spyOn(TodoForm.prototype, 'handleTxtChange');
    
    // override the implementation
    mocked.mockImplementation(() => "mock");

    const wrapper = shallow(<TodoForm />);

    wrapper.find("input[type='text']").simulate("change", { target: { value: "hello" } });

    expect(mocked).toHaveBeenCalled();
   
    mocked.mockRestore();
});
```

Comment: Thats tricky answer !!! actually i have over simplified my example here . What if I have to mock a event listener rather than spying it ??

Comment: getting error "Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given" as widow.prototype is undefined

Comment: I've deleted my previous comment and I've added how to mock your function instead of spying on it on the answer since what you're trying to achieve is mocking the event handler not the event itself.